# How can I find the comparison of specs and features of Android devices?

Tags: hardware, tech-specs

I recently got fed up with my previous smartphone (name omitted) and I'm considering switching to an Android-based phone.  However, I have been stumped by the sheer number of handsets.  I'm more than willing to change carriers and I have no preferences in keyboard style.

What I am looking for (and cannot find on Google) is a comparison of features between different Android phones so that I can make an educated decision (or at least whittle that decision down).

Answer (score 10):

*This is a community wiki. Feel free to [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/773/edit) and update the info*.

- [Wikipedia - List of Android smartphones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_smartphones): This link to Wikipedia shows a list of Android devices. It is recommended to click on Version twice, to sort with the latest Android version at the top.
- [GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/) has [a great tool to compare devices one to another](https://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3).
- [PhoneScoop](https://www.phonescoop.com/) has an excellent search engine and compares an extensive list of features side-by-side with differences highlighted automatically.
- [PhoneDB](https://phonedb.net/index.php?m=device&s=query): It's a bit overwhelming with all the options you have available to filter by, but it always seems up-to-date. It can also find phones other than Android.
- [PC Pro](https://pcpro.co.uk/) has a well-sorted [reviews section](https://www.pcpro.co.uk/reviews/smartphones) - click on Android (under OS) and you'll have a list. You can tick the boxes next to the phones and then a compare button will appear giving you a line-by-line comparison. Note this is a UK site and some phones have different names to the US versions.
- [ConsumerReports.org](https://www.consumerreports.org): If you're willing to pay a little, this site really does well at apples-to-apples comparisons on a wide variety of products, including cell phones.
- [Versus](https://versus.com/en/phone).