# Sites to search android devices based on features?

Tags: hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a comparison of Android devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/770/where-can-i-find-a-comparison-of-android-devices)

I've been doing research on various android devices, but I am having a hard time finding a good site to search devices based on features.

What are some good sites to search for android phones based on features? Thus far, I know of [DroidThing.com](http://droidthing.com), but it seems out of date.