# List of devices with screen parameters

Tags: hardware, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a comparison of Android devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/770/where-can-i-find-a-comparison-of-android-devices)

Is there any list with devices and their params? I'd like to know if this device is ldpi/mdpi/hdpi and what screen it is small/normal/large/etc.

For now most important for me is to know how Galaxy Note is described by those params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most comprehensive list I've ever seen is this article from Wikipedia: [Comparison of high-definition smartphone displays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_high-definition_smartphone_displays).

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it. Without dpi I cannot really know what layout the device will choose without having them.

Comment: You can use this simple formula to calculate DPI of each device given sceen resolution and size: DPI = sqrt(w^2+h^2)/s, where "w" and "h" are screen resolution and "s" is size. Using this formula for Note, it has DPI = 285. You can do it in spreadsheet, if you don't mind.

Comment: But still if you are programmer you don't know what is it DPI. For example HTC Flyer and Samsung Galaxy Tab (first generation) has the same resolution size etc. BUT one is HDPI and the second is MDPI device.

Comment: Unfortunately the link above does not work correctly.

Comment: @HosseinSeifi Updated the link since the old one is dead.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a list, so I made one myself **with DPI** :

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Answer (score 0):

[List of displays by pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density), which include many consumer devices.